# How do I create collision for all four sides of a wall in Flash CC?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cloud, collision

Here is my code:

```
/* Move with Keyboard Arrows
Allows the specified symbol instance to be moved with the keyboard arrows.

Instructions:
1. To increase or decrease the amount of movement, replace the number 5 below with the number of pixels you want the symbol instance to move with each key press.
Note the number 5 appears four times in the code below.
*/

stage.focus=stage;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

obj01_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDirection01);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, setPressed01);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, unsetPressed01);

function moveDirection01(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        obj01_mc.y -= 5;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        obj01_mc.y += 5;
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        obj01_mc.x -= 5;
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        obj01_mc.x += 5;
    }
}

function setPressed01(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function unsetPressed01(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
//Wall Collision
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,handleCollision);

function handleCollision( e:Event ):void{

    if(obj01_mc.hitTestObject(wall01_mc))
       {
           obj01_mc.x+=5;
       }
    if(obj01_mc.hitTestObject(wall02_mc))
       {
           obj01_mc.x-=5;
           obj01_mc.y-=5;      
           obj01_mc.width/10;
           obj01_mc.y+=10;
       }
    if(obj01_mc.hitTestObject(wall29_mc))
       {
           obj01_mc.x-=5;
       }
    if(obj01_mc.hitTestObject(wall13_mc))
       {
           obj01_mc.y+=5;
       }
    if(obj01_mc.hitTestObject(wall16_mc))
       {
           obj01_mc.y-=5;
       }
}
```

I'm having issues with wall02_mc, the other walls I have so far are only the borders and work fine for me. How do I make it so that obj_01 collides with all four sides of the wall, rather than half the sides it passes through?

Answer (score 0):

first of all I think you have to know the position of the object before the displacement when you test your collision to be able to place the object at the good position close the wall.

After that I think it's better to handle all your game logic in the same function and not to have 2 `ENTER_FRAME` events handlers.

Here is my suggestion:

```
stage.focus=stage;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, setPressed01);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, unsetPressed01);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameLoop);

function setPressed01( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:       upPressed = true;       break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN:     downPressed = true;     break;
        case Keyboard.LEFT:     leftPressed = true;     break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:    rightPressed = true;    break;

    }
}

function unsetPressed01( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:       upPressed = false;      break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN:     downPressed = false;    break;
        case Keyboard.LEFT:     leftPressed = false;    break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:    rightPressed = false;   break;
    }
}

/** the main game loop **/
function gameLoop( event:Event ):void
{
    // get the object position
    var x:int = obj01_mc.x;
    var y:int = obj01_mc.y;

    // calculate your move
    if( upPressed )     y -= 5;
    if( downPressed )   y += 5;
    if( leftPressed )   x -= 5;
    if( rightPressed )  x += 5;

    // do the collition test and the placement of your object
    placeObject( obj01_mc, wall01_mc, x, y );
    placeObject( obj01_mc, wall02_mc, x, y );
    placeObject( obj01_mc, wall29_mc, x, y );
    placeObject( obj01_mc, wall13_mc, x, y );
    placeObject( obj01_mc, wall16_mc, x, y );
}

/** place the object after the collision test **/
function placeObject( object:DisplayObject, collisionObject:DisplayObject, targetX:int, targetY:int ):void
{
    // pass through horizontally
    if( targetX > collisionObject.x-object.width && targetX < collisionObject.x+collisionObject.width )
    {
        // case pass trough by the left, return to the left border
        if( object.x < targetX )    object.x = collisionObject.x-object.width;
        // case pass trough by the right, return to the right border
        if( object.x > targetX )    object.x = collisionObject.x+collisionObject.width;
    }
    // no horizontal collision
    else
    {
        object.x = targetX;
    }

    // pass through vertically
    if( targetY > collisionObject.y-object.height && targetY < collisionObject.y+collisionObject.height )
    {
        // case pass trough by the up, return to the up border
        if( object.y < targetY )    object.y = collisionObject.y-object.height;
        // case pass trough by the bottom, return to the bottom border
        if( object.y > targetY )    object.y = collisionObject.y+collisionObject.height;
    }
    // no vertical collision
    else
    {
        object.y = targetY;
    }
}
```

***Note:** in this example your functions `handleCollision` and `moveDirection01` have been replaced by `gameLoop` function. So just the `gameLoop` function react to the `ENTER_FRAME` Event.*

I hope this could help you :)

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: 1114 The public attribute can only be used inside a package.

Comment: That was an error on my part, my bad. I got an error, and I tried solving it with codes that gave me another error, heh. Going back to your code, not sure if this is the same error, because I can't find any solutions (thankfully I can't mess up the code again). But, I'm getting errors on lines 9 through 12. Error 1120: Access of undefined Property upPressed/downPressed/rightPressed/leftPressed

Comment: Edit: I added: stage.focus=stage;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;" To the beginning of the code, and that stopped the error! But now can't move obj01_mc, haha.

Comment: The above would send me back to my original code, heh, so scratch that. Would something similar to "obj01_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);" work? tried that code and it didn't ;;

Comment: i just edited the post and added all your original code you have to keep to have your code working